# Clear input buffer including newline

Tags: c++, boost, input, timer, flush

I have a timer thread that executes five seconds in the future and a loop to wait for it to finish executing. Then the program finishes when the user hits enter. I noticed that while waiting for the loop, enter is accepted into the input buffer, and used to finish the program, and any subsequent enter hits are entered *onto the command line*!

I want to ignore all input that was entered before "press enter to exit" including enter. It's been a while since I worked with C++ and I can't remember how to do this (I have searched SO and Google and can't find an answer to this specific question). Here is the my example:

```
std::cout << "Timer test: wait 5 seconds\n";
boost::asio::io_service test_io;
deadline_timer test_timer(test_io, posix_time::seconds(5));

int testInt = 0;
auto asynctest = [&testInt](const boost::system::error_code&) {
    std::cout << "Running asynctest()\n";
    testInt = 5;
};

std::cout << "Starting asynchtest, which should output in 5 seconds\n";
test_timer.async_wait(boost::bind<void>(asynctest, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

while(testInt != 5) {
    std::cout << ". ";
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(200));
}

// How do I clear all input from the input stream here so that if the user hit enter
//    during the timer countdown it will be cleared and user still must hit enter to
//    exit program?

std::cout << "Press enter to exit\n";
std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
return 1;
```

adsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this at the purely C++ level; you'll have to drop
down to the OS level, or use some third party library like curses (or
maybe some asynchronous IO library, if you can get them to read `cin`
asynchronously).

Comment: This cannot be done with some facilities of Boost? Also, incidentally I am working in Visual C++, and apparently MS provides facilities to do this (untested - see http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.language/2007-01/msg00389.html), but that kind of defeats the purpose as this is not production code but a self-test to see how rusty I am.

Comment: @taz I don't know how `boost::asio` interacts with an open `istream`; in principle, at least, if you can connect an asynchronous input to the stream you're interested in, you can read and throw out everything that's in it, using non-blocking reads.  I'd probably not try to make it work with `cin`, however; the interactions between asynchronous reading and `cin`s buffer are likely to be unspecified.

Comment: Well apparently I'm rusty enough to immediately attempt something the standard doesn't support. From preliminary research it appears you're right and this might work with `boost::asio`, possibly needing threads. C++ iostreams _do not do_ non-blocking IO.  

I'm not going to test this further because I'm just practicing. Hopefully this saves someone some headache in the future. Thanks for you help.  

Further reading:  
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/538714-asynchronous-console-input/  
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/841283-how-make-non-blocking-call-cin